# An example of a $4×4$ matrix $A$ such that $A\not= I$, $A^2\not=I$, ..., $A^5 = I$

Tags: matrices

How do I go about solving this? I went for tutoring and the tutor said I am trying to get to an Identity matrix so I should start with an identity matrix and mix the values around till I get a solution. I have worked on this for 2 hours now and there has to be an easier way. Please help!

Comment: Well, what matrices have you tried doing this with? (Also, I assume these need to be with real coefficients?)

Comment: I had to do this for a 3x3 and all I did was plug in 1 and 0 in different places. The same has been done with 4x4 but there are so many combinations and being computationally intense there has to be an easier way to calculate what will make A*A*A*A*A = I

Comment: If you make the matrix with just $1$'s and $0$'s and exactly one $1$ in each row and column, then you will not get a matrix with the property you want.

Comment: Does this matrix have to have real entries?  If not, you can just put a primitive 5th root of unity down the diagonal...

Comment: [Dirac Matrices](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiracMatrices.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way is to ensure that $A^4+A^3+A^2+A+I=0$. Since $A$ is $4\times 4$, it is actually inevitable to find a non-zero polynomial of degree $4$ satisfied by $A$. Since $A^5-I=0$ but $A-I\ne0$, the polynomial I suggested is simply the factor $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ of $x^5-1$.

An $A$ with this property is $$ \begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0&-1 \\ 1&0&0&-1\\ 0&1&0&-1\\ 0&0&1&-1\end{bmatrix}.$$
In fact, if you want an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ to satisfy a degree $n$ polynomial $$p(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1} +x^n,$$ that is, $p(A)=0$, make $e_{i+1}$ the $i$th column of $A$ for $i<n$, and make the last column $(-a_0,-a_1,\dots,-a_{n-1})^T$.

---

As mentioned in the comments, this matrix is called the *companion* of $p$. It has the property that $p(A)=0$, and if $q(A)=0$, then $p$ divides $q$ (as polynomials), that is, $p$ is the *minimal polynomial* of $A$.

The [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) gives us that for any $n\times n$ matrix $B$, we have $r(B)=0$ where $r(x)$ is the *characteristic polynomial* of $B$, $r(x)=\det(xI-B)$. This is a monic polynomial of degree $n$. In particular, since $p$ has degree $n$ and is monic, we have that $p$ is also the characteristic polynomial of its companion matrix $A$.

To see that $p(A)=0$ we can of course just multiply. But let me show in general that this holds, and that $p$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$: Think about the specific $4\times 4$ example we have, and note that $e_1$, $Ae_1=e_2$, $A^2e_1=Ae_2=e_3$, and $A^3e_1=AA^2e_1=Ae_3=e_4$ are independent, so $A$ cannot satisfy a nonzero polynomial $s(x)=\alpha+\beta x+\gamma x^2+\delta x^3$ of degree $3$ or less, since $$s(A)e_1=(\alpha I+\beta A+\gamma A^2+\delta A^3)e_1=\alpha e_1+\beta e_2+\gamma e_3+\delta e_4 $$ is a nontrivial linear combination of basis vectors. On the other hand, $$A^4e_1=Ae_4=-e_1-e_2-e_3-e_4=-e_1-Ae_1-A^2e_1-A^3e_1, $$ so
 $$ p(A)e_1=(A^4+A^3+A^2+A+I)e_1=0. $$
Also, $p(A)e_2=p(A)Ae_1=Ap(A)e_1=A0=0$, and similarly $p(A)e_3=p(A)e_4=0$. But then $p(A)v=0$ for any $v$ that is a linear combination of $e_1,\dots,e_4$, that is, for any $v$, and therefore $p(A)=0$.

Comment: This is called the companion matrix, and its minimal polynomial is equal to its characteristic polynomial, which ensures that $I\not\in\{A,A^2,A^3,A^4\}$.

Comment: This kind of makes more sense to me. Thanks a lot I really appreciate the help!

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thanks! I had to run, so did not have time to add this at first. I have added a remark.

Answer (score 11):

The matrix $A_\theta=\begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta\end{bmatrix}$ corresponds to a rotation of $\theta$ radians. Choose $\theta$ such that $A_\theta^5 = I$. Then figure out how to 'expand' $A_\theta$ to be a $4 \times 4$ matrix.

Comment: Thank copper but I have no idea how to do this. My professor never talked about any of this and mostly talks theory which is why I went to tutoring to begin with. Are you suggesting that $A_\theta^5 = I$ should be a rotation of 5 radians?

Comment: Do you see how to choose $\theta$ to get $A^5 = I$? Mabe try drawing a picture?

Comment: @HermesTrismegistus:  If $A$ rotates by $\theta$, then $A^5$ rotates by $\theta$ five times, resulting in a total rotation of $5\theta$.  Rotating by $5$ radians five times would rotate by $25$ radians, which is not what $I$ does.

Comment: Thanks guys but I don't understand what you are saying and I'm sorry if I have wasted your time.

Comment: If you pick any vector  $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and any angle $\theta$, then the vector $A_\theta v$ is the vector $v$ rotated anti-clockwise by $\theta$ radians. Maybe try a few examples to convince yourself. If you choose the rotation to be $\frac{360}{5}$°, then applying the matrix 5 times will eventually rotate it back on itself.

Comment: Thanks again copper, this helps in understanding what is actually happening!

Comment: Good luck! ${}{}{}$